# Eventtrigger in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Created user control. Control has a field that does not support commands and I decided to use the event trigger to call the command. But it does not work. The application follows the MVVM pattern. Tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Create DP in UserControl for binding property:

```
    public ICommand EditorFormula {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(EditorFormulaProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EditorFormulaProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EditorFormulaProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EditorFormula", typeof(ICommand), typeof(FormIndexControl), null);
```

Create control in my UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UControls.FormIndexControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:wpfm="clr-namespace:WpfMath.Controls;assembly=WpfMath"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="200" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <wpfm:FormulaControl Formula="{Binding Path=IndexFormula}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=EditorFormula}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </wpfm:FormulaControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Binding UserControl XAML:

```
<uc:FormIndexControl EditorFormula="{Binding DataContext.CommandOpenEditor , RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

And create command. DelegateCommand class is implemented ICommand interface(It sure works):

```
public class test{

    public test(){
        CommandOpenEditor = new DelegateCommand(OpenEditorFormula);
        }

public ICommand CommandOpenEditor { get; set; }

    private void OpenEditorFormula(object obj) {
        // He not invoked
    }
}
```

Comment: Try debugging and see if your UC is getting proper dataContext

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your Output window? I am sure you will see a binding error for the Command. Because the binding will try to find the command in the datacontext of the usercontrol which is your window hosting the usercontrol.

Also you need to make the StackPanel Focusable because panels are not focusable by default.

So you can name the contorl and set the ElementName property in the InvokeCommandAction.

Here is the updated code.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="WpfApp4.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Name="usercontrol1"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel
        Height="50"
        Background="Aqua"
        Focusable="True"
        IsHitTestVisible="True">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LeftButtonDownCommand, ElementName=usercontrol1}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <TextBox Text="test" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>

<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel
        Focusable="True"
        IsHitTestVisible="True"
        Orientation="Vertical">


        <local:UserControl1 LeftButtonDownCommand="{Binding ButtonCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

public class MainViewModel
    {
        public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; set; }
        public MainViewModel()
        {

            ButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => { MessageBox.Show("Left Clicked"); });
        }
    }

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use relative source as well. If do not wanna use the name <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LeftButtonDownCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}}}" />